# if, else if, else statements: Within the blocks of code

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, netbeans, switch-statement

I am a beginner programmer, and am currently banging my head against the wall over this assignment.
I have to create a program that 'simulates' the use of a car, so it goes: drive, park, and fill up. The first thing it does is ask for how many litres of gas your tank can hold, and how many litres is currently in the tank. Then, it asks the user if it wants to a) drive, b) fill up, or c)park. I need to grab a user input (which I already know how to do), and depending on whether the user enters a,b, or c, it goes to this certain block of code and runs it.

Here are the specific instructions on what a, b, and c have to do:
a) Drive: 
1. enter the amount of Km driven (user inputs this)
2. Output how many litres of gas were used, and the amount of gas remaining in the tank. (we assume the car uses an average of 0.1 L/Km)

b) Fill up
1. User must enter the number of litres they wish to add
2. Output number of litres in tank. (the user can't input more litres than the tank can hold)

c) Park 
1. Output number of litres in tank, and total number of Km driven.
2. This exits the loop

Am I using the right kind of loop? How do I get the code to run an equation (look at the red underlined lines)? Please help me, I'm so lost.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many litres of gas can your tank hold?");
        int litreCap = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("How much gas is currently in your tank?");
        int startingLitre = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ok! Do you want to \n a) Drive \n b) Fill up, or \n c) Park");
        String abc = scan.next();
        String a, b, c;
        a = String.valueOf(1); //Wasn't sure if the problem had to do with the fact
        b = String.valueOf(2); //That I hadn't identified a,b and c
        c = String.valueOf(3);
        double litresUsed, gasTotal;

        if (abc .equals(a)) { //this is the drive section
            System.out.println("Please enter the amount of Kilometers driven.");
            int KmCount = scan.nextInt();
            litresUsed = 0.1*KmCount;//underlined yellow
            startingLitre - litresUsed = gasTotal;//this is underlined red
          }
        else if (abc .equals(b)){ //this is the fill up section
            System.out.println("OK! Please enter how many litres you are going to add.");
            int litresAdded = scan.nextInt(); //this is underlined yellow
            litresUsed + litresAdded = gasTotal; //underlined red
        }
        else {
            //enter c) Park code here
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I do not see any loop in your code? if a,b,and c are String, so what is abc ?  I never see you can concatenate strings like this?!!! **can you even run your code?**

Comment: let me suggest you put more descriptive names to variables, for instance, instead of `a`, use something like `driveSelected`. Something that will help you (and others after you) remember that the (a) option is the user wants to drive.

Comment: something else:
`startingLitre - litresUsed = gasTotal;`
remember that when you are assigning something to a variable, the target variable goes on the left, the source (expression, other variable, method executed) goes on the right side of the statement, like this:
`gasTotal = startingLitre - litresUsed;`

Comment: I added my last comment as an answer since that gets your code run an equation. Btw, @KickButtowski is right, there is no loop in your code.

Comment: @germanio your answer is look like a comment just friendly observation ;)

Comment: ahh... well, I took it from a friendly observation... if you know how to improve it, please give me some tips. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried to understand exactly what you are required to do as per your post. I would suggest the following corrections in your code:

1. You are required to finally print the number of kilometres run. So you have to introduced a new `int` variable say `runKm` and initialised to 0 before you start the loop like:

   ```
   int runKM = 0;
   ```
2. You have stated in your post that the program should loop till the user wants to exit the loop choosing first "c" and then `2`. So In order to have a loop, you have to introduced a `while` Loop with a new `boolean` variable say `continued` initialised to `true` and start a `while` loop with the variable `continued` as its check condition and finally close it after all the `if - else` blocks Like this:

   ```
   boolean continued = true;
   while(continued){
   //The checking conditions are implemented
   }
   ```

   This results to looping till the user select `c` and then `2`.
3. I would suggest you changed the `scan.next()` to `scan.nextLine()` to filter out incorrect inputs from users which would be handled by the `else` condition of the `if - else` block.
4. `String a, b, c` as they are not required so remove them with their references in the program.
5. Now you have to changed the conditions of  the `if` and `else if` to compare the input directly to the `String` value required So that you do not require variables `a, b, c`. like this:

   ```
   abc.equals("a") //instead of abc.equals(a)
   abc.equals("b") //instead of abc.equals(b)
   ```
6. In the `a` condition of the `if-else` block, you require to add a new line `runKM += KmCount;` to keep track of all the kilometres run. this can also be written as `runKM = runKM + KmCount;` both are equivalent.
7. You require to corrected the line `litresUsed + litresAdded = gasTotal`, which is basically an equality equation in mathematics and not an assignment operator in programming, to `startingLiter = startingLitre - litresUsed;` as you have to keep track of all the amount of gas used and the amount of gas filled up. This statement could have been written as `startingLiter -= litresUsed;` both are equivalent.
8. You require to corrected your mathematics equation `litresUsed + litresAdded = gasTotal;`, which does not make any sense, to the programming statement `startingLitre = startingLitre + litresAdded;` as you are basically adding to you amount left in the tank.
9. You have to write the new `else if` condition for the `c` input. It requires a second input of `1` or `2` as stated in your original post. And based on the second input if `1` then it prints the status i.e. KM run and Litre in tank. and `2` or any other `int` it changes the `continued` variable to `false` which results to exiting of the `while loop`. like this:

   ```
   else if(abc.equals("c")) {
       System.out.println("OK! Parked!!! What do you want to do?\n 1)Check your car status\n 2) exit ")
       int response = scan.nextInt();
       if(response == 1){
          System.out.println("Number of KM run = "+runKM +"\nAmount of litre in tank = "+startingLitre);
       }else {
          continued = false;
       }
   }
   ```
10. And finally you have to put an `else` condition which does not satisfy the user's input of either `a`, `b` or `c`. And write an appropriate message for the user and loop again like this.

    ```
    else{
       System.out.println("Wrong value entered. Please try again");
       continue;
    }
    ```

Comment: your post has been flagged as low quality answer. please provide some explanation.

Comment: @KickButtowski I hope that this will be ok now

Comment: I didn't vote u down but I'll try to study your answer and vote u up.

Comment: @KickButtowski I understand that this is spoon-feeding but how do you answer a person who does not know the difference between a programming statement and a mathematical equation.

Comment: by just giving hints code sample and explain as much as u can. u know others will see this post too. I agree with what u say, but get rid of your code and explain. I'm sure other will see ur post and u will have better outcome

Comment: I accept your suggestion and would implement it immediately.

Comment: I initially voted this down. Simply providing the solution to an problem is not a proper answer and does not provide insight or explanation. Your recent edit made it possible for OP to understand and *learn* from your answer, which IMHO, deserves an upvote.

Comment: @blip did not I tell ya?

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems there are a few little issues with the code you shared.

First:

```
String abc = scan.next();
String a, b, c;
a = String.valueOf(1);
b = String.valueOf(2);
c = String.valueOf(3);
```

If you want to read the user option from the command line, you may already have it in `abc` variable. Just use the if/if-else/else block to ask for the value of that variable.

Second:

```
startingLitre - litresUsed = gasTotal;
```

When you are assigning something to a variable, the target variable goes *on the left*, the source (an expression, equation, other variable, or even a method invocation) goes *on the right* side of the statement, like this:

```
gasTotal = startingLitre - litresUsed;
```

Hope this helps.
You can always check Oracle tutorials and class information, like this one:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html and this one:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Comment: OP should explain her own code, for me, it seems `abc` is intended for reading user input. But the main point is how the equations are run, which my answer explains.

Comment: @KickButtowski: that code has some mistakes, I agree, but I will not solve them all for him/her, the purpose of that exercise is to practise and learn, right?

Comment: I totally agree. but the rule is either have a complete answer or do not show anything. you can flag this post but what you have as answer is not complete and does not address all the  major issues that the op has.

Comment: sounds good but know giving the code answer is discouraged good luck

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for helping, I was able to clean up the code and take away all the unnecessary things. This is how it ended, and now it works perfectly (just in case someone stumbles on to this question and wants to see the final working product)! I have definitely learned a lot from this.

```
 public class CarGame {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many litres of gas can your tank hold?");
        int litreCap = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("How much gas is currently in your tank?");
        int startingLitre = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Ok! Do you want to \n a) Drive \n b) Fill up, or \n c) Park");
        String abc = scan.next();

        int litresUsed;
        int runKM = 0; //Kilometer counter (N.M 2015)

        boolean continued = true;//Keeps looping a, b, and c until user either parks or errs (N.M 2015)
        while(continued){

        if (abc .equals("a")) { //Drive section (N.M 2015)
            System.out.println("Please enter the amount of Kilometers driven.");
            int KmCount = scan.nextInt();
            litresUsed = (int) (0.1*KmCount);
            startingLitre = startingLitre - litresUsed;
            runKM = runKM + KmCount;
                if (startingLitre <= 0) { //this is the error
                    System.err.println("Uh-oh! You ran out of gas! Try again.");
                break; //If they run out of gas, the program ends like a game over (N.M 2015)
                }
            System.out.println("You used " + litresUsed + " litre(s) of gas. That leaves you with \n" + startingLitre + " litres of gas.");
            System.out.println("You have driven for " + runKM + " kilometers.");

            System.out.println("What do you want to do now? \n a) Drive \n b) Fill up, or \n c) Park");
            abc = scan.next();
            continued = true;
          }
        else if (abc .equals("b")){ //Fill up section (N.M 2015)
            System.out.println("OK! Please enter how many litres you are going to add.");
            int litresAdded = scan.nextInt();
            startingLitre = startingLitre + litresAdded;
                if (startingLitre > litreCap){ //this is the error
                System.err.println("Hey! That is too much gas! Your tank can only hold " + litreCap + " litres of gas!");
                break;
                }
            System.out.println("You added " + litresAdded + " litres of gas. Now, your car has " + startingLitre + " litres of gas.");

            System.out.println("What would you like to do now? \n a) Drive \n b) Fill up, or \n c) Park");
            abc = scan.next();
            continued = true;
        }
        else if (abc .equals("c")) { //Park section (N.M 2015)
            System.out.println("You have now parked!");
            System.out.println("Number of Km run: " + runKM + "\nAmount of litres in tank: " + startingLitre);
            continued = false; //ends program (N.M 2015)
        }
        else {
            continued = false; //ends program (N.M 2015)
        }
    }
    }

}
```